# Save dynamically generated javascript into html file OR get this content in a string and send to Controller

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 application where I render a View but most of the content is generated dynamically with javascript after I pass a parameter. I would like to know how I could either save all this html generated via javascript into a string (being able to use it in my controller) or save the html page as file.

Comment: Maybe you can use template engine like MustacheJS or HoganJS?

Answer (score 0):

it is not clear what is your process but you can do it at least two ways:

1. you can get rendered html markup using javascript  document.documentElement.outerHTML after document loaded, may be execute ajax call to post it to another action if that is what you trying to do.
2. from Chrome/FF, hit f12 and go to Elements/Inspector tab, then righ click on parent html node then on "Edit As HTML", it will show rendered html in textbox, you can copy it.

hope it helps.